# Any plugin/theme available which suits my requirement?

Tags: plugins, themes

[image: insighter]

I have this WordPress website up. As one can see I've displayed alternate red and blue bands (which are images) with text written on them. I had the bands (around 100) manually created on Photoshop fitting in different sentences on them which is very tedious and time consuming.
Are there any themes/plugins available where this kind of structure is available where I have to only add texts?
I've searched on the net but no luck so far.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for theme or plugin recommodations are off topic.

Comment: Who made that rule? This site is called wordpress answers isn't it?

Comment: If you had read the rules when you signed up you should have known it.

Comment: _This site is called wordpress answers isn't it?_ Yeah, we're working on that... ;)

Comment: Okay @Pieter I'll make sure I spend all my time reading the 1000+ lines of rule before posting any question. Thanks for your great help anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you'll find any themes or plugins designed for that *exact* purpose, but it wouldn't be hard to roll your own solution. For example, if you put your text in a post or page, with each "band" in it's own paragraph, you could add in some simple CSS to get the desired effect.

```
p {
    padding: 50px;
    color: white;
}

p:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }

p:nth-child(even) { background: blue; }
```

Here's a sample JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/4thUh/